# How do you change icons for push notifications in the Notification Center for iOS apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Push notifications in the Notification Center (top area) show an old app icon for our iOS app. Specifically, it shows the icon from our app's version 1.0, but we swapped out icons for new ones starting with the subsequent release.

How do we change our app icon for push notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to the released version? If not, then try a "clean" build.

If so, then check your plist file and make sure all of the icon settings are correct.

I've only experienced this while debugging and a clean build fixed everything.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to clean twice + clean build folder. I hate voodoo fixes

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the Notification Center uses the same icon that Spotlight uses, maybe you added one of those to your project and didn't update it?

[Apple's reference on app icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html)